# Flask and sqlite, How to make a search engine and retrieve data from sqlite database and display it through HTML?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I am trying to create a search engine where the search will happen through a reference number provided to customers and from that reference number their all details will be displayed on a webpage. I have created an HTML page name as Track.html and the main python code is below. please help I am new to programming.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Track</title>
</head>
<body>
<body bgcolor="lightblue">
<center>
<h1><font size="7" color="purple" face="Russo one">TRACK YOUR COMPLAINT:</font></h1>
</center>
<FORM action="{{url_for('track')}}"method="post">
    <p>
    <br>
        <b>Reference number:</b>
        <input type="text" name="Reference_number" value="{{request.form.track}}"><br/>
    </p>
    <p><br>
         <input type="Submit" name="request" value="Submit"><br/>
      </p>
      <b><H2>{{records}}</H2></b>
       <a href="complaint.html"> Click here to submit your complaint.</a>

</FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

```
@app.route('/Track.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def track():
    if request.method == "POST":
        conn = db_connect()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.executemany('''select * from complaint_application where Reference_number = %s''', request.form['track'])
        return render_template("Track.html", records=cur.fetchall())
    return render_template('Track.html')
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port='5000')
```

Comment: Please state what exact problem you have.

Comment: @JakubBláha I am not able to retrieve data from database and displayed it the on the html page, the above snippet is of that only but seems something is wrong in that.And it is showing no error but still the code is not working.

Comment: I would try `print`ing the `cur.fetchall()` result before passing it as a keyword argument to see if the SQL statement is broken or the Jinja template itself is broken.

Comment: Also, try changing the method in the `if` statement to `GET`.